# Windows Command Prompt -- Empty Directory

Tags: windows, directory, command-prompt

I'm experiencing a strange problem with my Windows Shell. It seems whenever I move to my "My Documents" directory in command prompt and run the command "ls" I receive no information about the contents of the directory.  But, when I browse to this directory using explorer I see all the contents as normal.  I can also cd to any of the sub-directories without problems.  I also get no results back when I browse to "My Documents" using the explorer in another program.

This is becoming really frustrating as I need to access sub-directories here quite frequently.

Answer (score 5):

window shell commands are different than unix. I think you need to use 'dir'.

Isn't it telling you that 'ls' is not recognized as an internal or external command...?